# cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified exception on get_or_insert

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions

We're loading a list of emails from file while putting a large number of datastore entities concurrently for each email address and getting occasional errors in the form:

```
BadRequestError: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG
```

The failing Python method call:

```
EmailObj.get_or_insert(key_name=email, source=source, reason=reason)
```

where email is the address string and source and reason are StringProperties.

Question: how can the get_or_insert call start a transaction for one simple datastore model (2 string properties) and get entities involved of different groups? I expect the method above should either read the existing object matching the given key or store the new entity.

Comment: Have you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776823/cross-group-transaction-error-with-only-one-entity?

Comment: Yes I've looked through the questions surrounding this error. The answers are mostly handwaving about the missing parent parameter but I have yet to see a clear answer explaining which groups are involved in this particular transaction. The error seems to imply that at least 2 entities were attempted to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I don't know the exact internal implementation, this is just a theory...

Since you didn't specify a parent then there is no entity group that could be "locked"/established from the beginning as **the** group to which the transaction would be limited to.

The `get_or_insert` operation would normally be a check if the entity with that keyname exists and, if not, then create a new entity. Without a parent, this new entity would be in its own group, let's call it `new_group`.

Now to complete the transaction automatically associated with `get_or_insert` a conflict check would need to be done.
The conflict would mean an entity with the same keyname was created by one of the concurrent tasks (after our check that such entity exists but before our transaction end), which entity would also have its own, *different* group, let's call it `other_group`.

This very conflict check, only in the case in which the conflict is real, would effectively access both `new_group` and `other_group`, causing the exception.

By specifying a parent the issue doesn't exist, since both `new_group` and `other_group` would actually be the same group - the parent's group. The `get_or_insert` transaction would be restricted to this group.

The theory could be verified, I think, even in production (the errors are actually harmless if the theory is correct - the addresses are after all duplicates)

First step would be to confirm that the occurences are related to the **same** email address being inserted twice in a very short time - concurently.

Wrap in try/except the exception and log the corresponding email address, then check it against the input files - they should be duplicates and I imagine located quite close to each-other in the file.

Then you could force that condition - intentionally inserting duplicate addresses every 5-10 emails (or some other rate you consider relevant).

Depending on how the app is actually implemented you could insert the duplicates in the input files, or, if using tasks - create/enqueue duplicate tasks, or simply call the `get_or_insert` twice (not sure if the last one will be effective enough as it may happen on the same thread/instance). Eventually log or keep track of the injected duplicated addresses

The occurence rate of the exception *should* now increase, potentially proportionally with the forced duplicate insertion rate. Most if not all of the corresponding logged addresses should match the tracked duplicates being injected.

If you got that far the duplicate entries being the trigger is confirmed. What would be left to confirm would be the different entity groups for the same email address - I can't think of a way to check that exactly, but I also can't think of some other group related to the duplicate email addresses.

Anyways, just add `xg=True` in the `get_or_insert` calls' [context options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions#context_options) and, if my theory is correct, the errors *should* dissapear :)

Comment: Thanks, it sounds plausible. Earlier today a suggestion was given that maybe the get_or_insert had joined an existing transaction but I ruled that our later by surrounding the get_or_insert call with a try/except and logging db.is_in_transaction() which returned false for all cases so it looks certain that the only transaction in play is from get_or_insert down. That leaves only two entities (one would think).

Comment: The usage of XG resolved it (had to copy the get_or_insert function to a get_or_insert_xp version that passes the xg=True flag). I guess we'll just have to live without knowing precisely what's happening under the covers in this scenario.